# java bounded wildcards understanding issue

Tags: java

I am new to java and I read many articles on the net about `? super T` or `? extends T` but I still don't get it. Here is my example:

```
public class A<T> {

    private T t;

    public T getT() {
        return t;
    }

    public void setT(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void doExtends(A<? extends T> b) {
        T t = b.getT();      //ok
        this.setT(b.getT()); // ok
        b.setT(this.getT()); // error
    }
    public void doSuper(A<? super T> b) {
        T t = b.getT();       // error
        this.setT(b.getT()); // error
        b.setT(this.getT()); // ok
    }
}
```

why are there errors? my question is different then the one referenced in comments

Comment: What errors? can you please show us the stack trace?

Comment: @ItamarG3 read my commends in code.. it wont compile

Comment: But what's the type of the exception? I noticed what lines are causing this, but I can't know exactly which Exception is being thrown. Btw, don't worry about the downvotes. If you read (future tense) the [ask] page, then I'm sure it would happen less in future questions you post

Comment: @ItamarG3 There are no exception thrown, OP has compile errors.

Comment: In doSuper b.getT() returns a super type to T, it might be an Object. You can add `T`s to it, but you cannot get a `T` out.

Comment: Please include the compiler error message

Comment: @ItamarG3 i read that article but its not helping me

Comment: why -2 points? whats wrong with my question.. I am not using List<T>.. this question is different

Comment: @user8354588 did you read the answer? because the **answer** would be almost the same.

Comment: @ItamarG3 I read it yesterday and its not the same to me

Comment: @user8354588 first, it's best not to *demand* anything, and\or to be rude. Secondly, it doesn't work because `b` ***is not related to*** `T`. Its generic type (the type inside the `<>`) is `T`, but it is not `T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is as follows:

In `doExtends(A<? extends T> b)` you specify that `b` is of type `A` encapsulating something that may be an **unknown** subclass of `T`. As such it is perfectly fine to do `T t = b.getT()` since `b.getT()` produces something `extends T` (so you can cast to `T`). Same holds true for `this.setT(b.getT())` - equivalent to `this.setT(t)`. Now let's look at the method's last line `b.setT(...)`. As said before `A` contains an **unknown subclass** of `T`. But you want to stuff in a `T` (`this.getT()` produces `T`) and you cannot be sure that your `T` matches the **subclass** that may be inside `b` - that's why it doesn't work.

Next on to `doSuper(A<? super T> b)` - here `b` contains an **unknown superclass** of `T` or **maybe** `T` itself. That's why the last line - setting the value - is perfectly fine. `this.getT()` produces a `T` which you can always cast to any of the superclasses. However when you get the value with `b.getT()` you only known that it's an **unknown superclass** of `T` but **not guaranteed** to be a `T`. You essentially don't know what class it will be.

Comment: thanks man, great explaination